# Any tips on reducing wxWidgets application code size?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have written a minimal wxWidgets application:

stdafx.h

```
#define wxNO_REGEX_LIB
#define wxNO_XML_LIB
#define wxNO_NET_LIB
#define wxNO_EXPAT_LIB
#define wxNO_JPEG_LIB
#define wxNO_PNG_LIB
#define wxNO_TIFF_LIB
#define wxNO_ZLIB_LIB
#define wxNO_ADV_LIB
#define wxNO_HTML_LIB
#define wxNO_GL_LIB
#define wxNO_QA_LIB
#define wxNO_XRC_LIB
#define wxNO_AUI_LIB
#define wxNO_PROPGRID_LIB
#define wxNO_RIBBON_LIB
#define wxNO_RICHTEXT_LIB
#define wxNO_MEDIA_LIB
#define wxNO_STC_LIB

#include <wx/wxprec.h>
```

Minimal.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <memory>
#include <wx/wx.h>

class Minimal : public wxApp
{
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};

IMPLEMENT_APP(Minimal)
DECLARE_APP(Minimal)

class MinimalFrame : public wxFrame
{
    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
public:
    MinimalFrame(const wxString& title);
    void OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& e);
    void OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& e);
};

BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MinimalFrame, wxFrame)
    EVT_MENU(wxID_ABOUT, MinimalFrame::OnAbout)
    EVT_MENU(wxID_EXIT, MinimalFrame::OnQuit)
END_EVENT_TABLE()

MinimalFrame::MinimalFrame(const wxString& title)
    : wxFrame(0, wxID_ANY, title)
{
    std::auto_ptr<wxMenu> fileMenu(new wxMenu);
    fileMenu->Append(wxID_EXIT, L"E&xit\tAlt-X", 
        L"Terminate the Minimal Example.");
    std::auto_ptr<wxMenu> helpMenu(new wxMenu);
    helpMenu->Append(wxID_ABOUT, L"&About\tF1",
        L"Show the about dialog box.");

    std::auto_ptr<wxMenuBar> bar(new wxMenuBar);
    bar->Append(fileMenu.get(), L"&File");
    fileMenu.release();
    bar->Append(helpMenu.get(), L"&Help");
    helpMenu.release();

    SetMenuBar(bar.get());
    bar.release();

    CreateStatusBar(2);
    SetStatusText(L"Welcome to wxWidgets!");
}

void MinimalFrame::OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& e)
{
    wxMessageBox(L"Some text about me!", L"About", wxOK, this);
}

void MinimalFrame::OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& e)
{
    Close();
}

bool Minimal::OnInit()
{
    std::auto_ptr<MinimalFrame> mainFrame(
        new MinimalFrame(L"Minimal wxWidgets Application"));
    mainFrame->Show();
    mainFrame.release();
    return true;
}
```

This minimal program weighs in at 2.4MB! (Executable compression drops this to half a MB or so but that's still HUGE!) (I must statically link because this application needs to be single-binary-xcopy-deployed, so both the C runtime and wxWidgets itself are set for static linking)

Any tips on cutting this down? (I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can additionally set MSVC to compile for small binary size (but this might impact performance of course) by using the flag `/01`. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f8h5cxt.aspx). Also remember that wxWidgets will need to be compiled as such for this to have any impact.

And I think that 2.4 MB for a statically linked app is pretty decent IMHO...

**UPDATE**: the [wxWidgets wiki on executable size](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Reducing_Executable_Size) might bring some comfort...

Comment: The same app using WTL was 90 kb. I don't think 2.4MB is decent. It's nice that wxWidgets provides cross platform support, but not at the expense of a 27 fold ballooning in size.

Comment: That would surprise me for C++ code, as a simple iostream "hello world" compiled with `cl /MT /O1 main.cpp /link /out:test.exe` gives a size of 115 kB on MSVC 10. Are yout sure the WTL project was compiled completely statically?

Comment: @rubenvb: Yes, I'm sure. The command lines (generated by VC 10): http://pastebin.com/kzqZXAVP . Perhaps the size difference is caused by link-time-code-generation, which your commandline would not invoke.

Comment: (Actually I didn't keep my other 90kb example; I created a new project to just pull those command lines. It has a bit less functionality than the wxWidgets minimal app (no menu or anything), but it's 67kb now)

Comment: Let's not forget that most win-dependent stuff uses libraries that are already shipped with Windows, and this is one reason why using some Microsoft-made technologies make the resulting executables so small. For instance, if you make an hello world app using just plain Win32, you'll get just a few Kbs on the executable...

Comment: Rui: Yes, I know I should expect some code size increase simply because wxWidgets is an extensible framework for these things and there is code involved -- and that involves overhead. But 2.4MB for a minimal window if I don't need the cross platform aspect of it is not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

You should disable all the features you don't need by setting most of `wxUSE_XXX` in `include/wx/msw/setup.h` to 0. But even so, you still won't have anything near 90KB.

wxWidgets was simply never optimized for size so if this is your primary concern it's probably unsuitable for you (unless you want to do some work on this yourself, of course, which would be very welcome). In practice however it's never been a problem except, maybe, for a vanishingly few people.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the linker switches as follows:

```
/FILEALIGN:512 /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /INCREMENTAL:NO
```

These would reduce the size of your executable.

For a simple hello world program in C++, if you wish to compile from the command line, enter the following commands:

```
cl /MT /O1 main.cpp /link /FILEALIGN:512 /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /INCREMENTAL:NO /OUT:test.exe
```

If you try to check the executable, you will notice that the size is now much smaller.